# How do i interpret results from Keras predict_generator?

Tags: python, keras

I am performing binary classification of data. I am using predict_generator to obtain the classification results. The input to the predict_generator are 44 examples, 22 positive, 22 negative. The following is the output obtained:

```
[9.98187363e-01 1.81267178e-03]
[5.02341951e-04 9.99497652e-01]
[8.41189444e-01 1.58810586e-01]
[7.26610771e-04 9.99273360e-01]
[9.96826649e-01 3.17337317e-03]
[8.83008718e-01 1.16991334e-01]
[3.84130690e-04 9.99615788e-01]
[8.65039527e-01 1.34960532e-01]
[1.78014021e-03 9.98219788e-01]
[9.96107757e-01 3.89222591e-03]
[6.16264821e-04 9.99383688e-01]
[2.98170745e-03 9.97018337e-01]
[9.92357790e-01 7.64221745e-03]
[9.93237853e-01 6.76209433e-03]
[9.98248339e-01 1.75163767e-03]
[1.17816392e-03 9.98821795e-01]
[9.84322488e-01 1.56775210e-02]
[3.11790430e-03 9.96882081e-01]
[4.62388212e-04 9.99537587e-01]
[1.42699364e-03 9.98572946e-01]
[9.43281949e-01 5.67180961e-02]
[9.98008907e-01 1.99115812e-03]
[4.12312744e-04 9.99587715e-01]
[9.29474115e-01 7.05258474e-02]
[3.37766513e-04 9.99662280e-01]
[1.75693433e-03 9.98243093e-01]
[9.92154586e-04 9.99007881e-01]
[1.87152205e-03 9.98128474e-01]
[9.20654461e-02 9.07934546e-01]
[9.95722532e-01 4.27750358e-03]
[9.96877313e-01 3.12273414e-03]
[9.87601459e-01 1.23985587e-02]
[1.11398198e-01 8.88601840e-01]
[1.48968585e-02 9.85103130e-01]
[6.73048152e-03 9.93269503e-01]
[1.65761902e-03 9.98342395e-01]
[9.94634032e-01 5.36595425e-03]
[5.00697970e-01 4.99302000e-01]
[1.65578525e-03 9.98344183e-01]
[9.68859911e-01 3.11401486e-02]
```

CODE:

```
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_height = 299
img_width = 299
no_of_frames = 15
channels = 3
no_of_epochs = 50
batch_size_value = 60


cnn_base = Xception(input_shape=(img_width, img_height, channels),
                weights="imagenet", include_top=False, pooling='avg')

cnn_base.trainable = False


hidden_layer_1 = Dense(activation="relu", units=1024)(cnn_base.output)
drop_layer=Dropout(0.2)(hidden_layer_1)
hidden_layer_2 = Dense(activation="relu", units=512)(drop_layer)
outputs = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer_2)
model = Model(cnn_base.input, outputs)

nadam_optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, 
epsilon=1e-08, schedule_decay=0.004)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
  optimizer=nadam_optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])



# for data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( zoom_range=.1, rotation_range=8, 
width_shift_range=.2, height_shift_range=.2)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/Train',  # this is the target directory
    target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
    batch_size=batch_size_value,
    class_mode="categorical")


validation_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    '/home/Val',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size_value,
    class_mode="categorical")

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=no_of_epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=17,
    validation_steps=7)


Test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    '/home/Test',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size_value,
    class_mode="categorical")

Prob_val = model.predict_generator(test_set)
print((Prob_val))
```

I assume they are probabilities, but the column contains only 40 entries. How do they correspond with the 44 inputs example ?

Comment: which version of keras and tensorflow are you using? is this tf.keras?

Comment: Keras:2.2.4, tensorflow:1.15.0,

Comment: Mmmm that is odd, I have never had this problem with keras, can you include code that produces this outputs? Please include imports as well

Comment: This code does not run for me, if you notice the input_img is not connected to anything, so it produces a Graph disconnected error

Comment: I updated the code